# What does 'end of stream' mean when working with sockets

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming

When working with Sockets in Java, how can you tell whether the client has finished sending all (binary) data, before you could start processing them. Consider for example:

```
istream = new BufferedInputStream (socket.getInputStream());
ostream = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

int count;
while(istream.available() > 0 && (count = istream.read(buffer)) != -1)
{
    // do something..
}

// assuming all input has been read
ostream.write(getResponse());       
ostream.flush();
```

I've read similar posts on SO such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534964/why-is-the-end-of-the-input-stream-never-reached-using-java-sockets), but couldn't find a conclusive answer. While my solution above works, my understanding is that you can never really tell if the client has finished sending all data. If for instance the client socket sends a few chunks of data and then blocks waiting for data from another data source before it could send more data, the code above may very well assume that the client has finished sending all data since istream.available() will return 0 for the *current* stream of bytes.

Answer (score 27):

Yes, you're right - using `available()` like this is unreliable. Personally I very rarely use `available()`. If you want to read until you reach the end of the *stream* (as per the question title), keep calling `read()` until it returns -1. That's the easy bit. The hard bit is if you don't want the end of the stream, but the end of "what the server wants to send you at the moment."

As the others have said, if you need to have a conversation over a socket, you *must* make the protocol explain where the data finishes. Personally I prefer the "length prefix" solution to the "end of message token" solution where it's possible - it generally makes the reading code a lot simpler. However, it can make the *writing* code harder, as you need to work out the length before you send anything. This is a pain if you could be sending a lot of data.

Of course, you can mix and match solutions - in particular, if your protocol deals with both text and binary data, I would *strongly* recommend length-prefixing strings rather than null-terminating them (or anything similar). Decoding string data tends to be a lot easier if you can pass the decoder a complete array of bytes and just get a string back - you don't need to worry about reading to half way through a character, for example. You could use this as part of your protocol but still have overall "records" (or whatever you're transmitting) with an "end of data" record to let the reader process the data and respond.

Of course, all of this protocol design stuff is moot if you're not in control of the protocol :(

Comment: The length-prefix as suggested by you/others sounds like a valid solution for conversations using the same socket conn. But assuming we are dealing with a one-time send/receive cycle, would the same approach be ideal here? The reason I ask follows your note "keep calling read() until it (contd.)

Comment: returns -1"  What does end-of-stream actually mean, and what does it mean to keep reading until read() returns -1? Closing the client socket's output-stream would certainly be an end of stream to the server socket, but that isn't really useful if we intend to send back something over the same conn.

Comment: So it seems to me that checking for end-of-stream (i.e -1) is only useful in a one-way message between a client and server, where the client socket is subsequently closed after sending a message.

Comment: Well, it can be two ways like HTTP 1.0 - client makes a request, server recognises the end of the request, responds, and closes the socket when it finishes the response. But yes, it's for "one shot" messaging rather than a conversation.

Comment: What I'm not immediately sure of (which is somewhat shocking) is whether the two streams are effectively independent - whether you can close the client to server output stream, let the server's *input* stream see "end of data" and then the server respond with data. Worth checking.

Comment: The trouble with closing the client to server output stream is that it closes the client socket as well, not just the stream. So while the server can potentially send back data, we can't receive it.

Comment: So I wonder, when does an "end of stream" really occur apart from the client closing the socket? I can't think of a proper example where I'd  use "keep calling read() until it returns -1" except for a one-way message, where a client only needs to send data and not receive, ie:open->send data->close.

Answer (score 7):

I think this is the task more of a protocol, assuming that you are the man who writes both the transmitting and receiving sides of application.
For example you could implement some simple logic protocol and divide you data into packets. Then divide packets into two parts: the head and the body. And then to say that your head consists of a predefined starting sequence and contains number of bytes in the body. Of forget about starting sequence and simpy transfer number of bytes in the bofy as a first byte of the packet.
Then you've could solve you problem.

Comment: +1 to Nikita's answer. If the sender does not close the stream after  sending a single message (HTTP keep-alive, for (well-known) example), there is no way you can tell whether all data was transmitted. You _have_ to define the boundaries of your message in the protocol  or state (see next comment)

Comment: (cont'd) (again, in the protocol) that all data must be sent in a single chunk. The latter is very unreliable solution, though.

Answer (score 4):

As some ppl already said you can't avoid some kind of protocol for communication. 
It should look like this for example:

On the server side you have:

```
 void sendMSG(PrintWriter out){
    try {
        //just for example..
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c dir C:");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            p.getInputStream()));

        //and then send all this crap to the client
        String s = "";
        while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
          out.println("MSG");
          out.println(s);
        }
      } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Command incorrect!");
      }
      out.println("END");
}
//You are not supposed to close the stream or the socket, because you might want to send smth else later..
```

On the client side you have:

```
void recieveMSG(BufferedReader in) {
    try {
      while (in.readLine().equals("MSG")) {
        System.out.println(in.readLine());
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("Connection closed!");
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

as [Nikita](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4378/nikita-borodulin) said this is more of task of protocol. Either you can go by header and body approach or you can send a special character or symbol for end of stream to break processing loop. Something like if you send say '[[END]]' on socket to denote end of stream.